# unfocusable edittext not working in device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm trying to make **uneditable/unclickable/unfocusable edit text**. And i'm successful on emulator but when i'm trying my code into **device(android 4.0) not working**.

Below my xml and code:-

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tee_tea_Boss"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tee_tea_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/calbox"
    android:ems="10"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="#888888"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoEnterAction"
    android:textSize="25sp" >
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**code**

```
        tee_tea_edit_text.setEnabled(false);
        tee_tea_edit_text.setFocusable(false);
        tee_tea_edit_text.setClickable(false);
        tee_tea_edit_text.setKeyListener(null);
        tee_tea_edit_text.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

try above code in my activity but its not working on device .Before ask try so many things but not working for me.

**I do not want above thing in xml.**

Comment: Is "tee_tea_edit_text EditText" your first view in xml file? if so try moving it to second position.

Comment: @Rekha i can update my xml file..

Comment: I have executed your code in my android 4.0.4 as it is, with above xml file it works perfect..what problem does you face in your device?

Comment: what you want hide soft keyboard input???

Comment: @altaf i just want edittext not clickable or editable??

Comment: @Hemant did find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attributes in xml file.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: this.tee_tea_edit_text.setFocusable(false); try this let you know

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
mEdit.setKeyListener(null);
```